# Crear campo input de forma dinámica en un form dinámico cuando selecciono una opción en un select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy tratando de crear un formulario que contiene un select option que al seleccionar la opción verificar muestre un botón de agregar campos de opciones, el problema es que a la hora de agregar 2 preguntas, seleccionar verificar en ambas y agregar campos de opciones, cuando quiero agregar mas campos de opciones en la primer pregunta creada las duplica, crea campos de opciones de dos en dos. Agradezco su ayuda Gracias!

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.verificar').hide();
            $('.duplicate').hide();

            var count = 2;

            //duplicate
            $('a.add').on('click', function() {

                //clone
                var row = $('.duplicate').clone();
                $(row).insertAfter('.duplicate-btn');
                $(row).show();

                //add new ids
                $(row).find('select').attr('id', 'select_' + count);
                $(row).find('verificar').attr('id', 'verificar_' + count);

                //remove duplicate class
                $(row).removeClass('duplicate');

                //onchange of select
                $('select').on('change', function() {

                    var value = $(this).val();
                    var select = $(this).parent();
                    if (value == 1) {
                        $(select).siblings('.inputed').show();
                        $(select).siblings('.ocultar').hide();
                    } else {
                        $(select).siblings('.inputed').hide();

                    }
                    if (value == 2) {
                        $(select).siblings('.ocultar').show();
                        $(select).siblings('.verificar').show();
                    } else {
                        $(select).siblings('.verificar').hide();
                        $(select).siblings('.ocultar').show();
                    }

                });

                //click of remove pregunta
                $(".up-box-question").on("click", ".remove-aditional", function() {

                    $(this).closest(".all").remove();

                });

                $(".optionRow").on("click", ".remove-option", function() {

                    $(this).closest(".option-row").remove();

                });
                //Agrega opciones
                $(".addRow").click(function() {
                    var html = "<div class='option-row' id='rowtk" + count + "'><div class='form-group'><div class='input-group select'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Añade opción' /><span class='input-group-btn'><button class='btn btn-primary remove-option' type='button'><a class='remove-tipe' href='javascript: void(0)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' style='color:white'></span></a></button></span></div></div></div>";

                    var form = $(html);

                    $(this).closest(".verificar").find(".optionRow").append(form);

                });
            });
            count++;

        });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="aditional-questions aditionals text">
        <div class="aditional-box duplicate-btn">
                <p class="aditional-text" for="">Pregunta
                    <a class="btn btn-primary agregar add" href="javascript: void(0)" type="button"><span></span>Agregar</a>
                </p>
        </div>
        <div class="duplicate all">
            <div class="up-box-question" style="text-align: center">
                <a class="remove-aditional" href="javascript: void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-question" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="type-question-text">Tipo de Pregunta</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select class="form-control select" name="">
                                            <option value="1">Text</option>
                                            <option value="2">Verificar</option>
                                           </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row ocultar">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="type-question-text" for="">Titulo</label>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="" class="form-control text general" placeholder="Número de indentificación">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row verificar">
                        <div class="text option" style="margin-top:10px; text-align: center">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary addRow" href="javascript: void(0)" type="button"><span></span>Agregar Opcion</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="optionRow">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en que el evento click de `$(".addRow").click(function()` se duplicaba. Para corregir eso coloque un `$(".addRow").unbind("click");` para que no se repitiera quedando asi:

```
$(".addRow").unbind("click");
$(".addRow").click(function(){
...
```

Puedes probarlo con tu código así:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            $('.verificar').hide();
            $('.duplicate').hide();

            var count = 2;

            //duplicate
            $('a.add').on('click', function() {

                //clone
                var row = $('.duplicate').clone();
                $(row).insertAfter('.duplicate-btn');
                $(row).show();

                //add new ids
                $(row).find('select').attr('id', 'select_' + count);
                $(row).find('verificar').attr('id', 'verificar_' + count);

                //remove duplicate class
                $(row).removeClass('duplicate');

                //onchange of select
                $('select').on('change', function() {

                    var value = $(this).val();
                    var select = $(this).parent();
                    if (value == 1) {
                        $(select).siblings('.inputed').show();
                        $(select).siblings('.ocultar').hide();
                    } else {
                        $(select).siblings('.inputed').hide();

                    }
                    if (value == 2) {
                        $(select).siblings('.ocultar').show();
                        $(select).siblings('.verificar').show();
                    } else {
                        $(select).siblings('.verificar').hide();
                        $(select).siblings('.ocultar').show();
                    }

                });

                //click of remove pregunta
                $(".up-box-question").on("click", ".remove-aditional", function() {

                    $(this).closest(".all").remove();

                });

                $(".optionRow").on("click", ".remove-option", function() {

                    $(this).closest(".option-row").remove();

                });
                //Agrega opciones
                $(".addRow").unbind("click");
                $(".addRow").click(function() {
                    var html = "<div class='option-row' id='rowtk" + count + "'><div class='form-group'><div class='input-group select'><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Añade opción' /><span class='input-group-btn'><button class='btn btn-primary remove-option' type='button'><a class='remove-tipe' href='javascript: void(0)'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' style='color:white'></span></a></button></span></div></div></div>";
                    
                    var form = $(html);

                    $(this).closest(".verificar").find(".optionRow").append(form);

                });
            });
            count++;

        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="aditional-questions aditionals text">
        <div class="aditional-box duplicate-btn">
                <p class="aditional-text" for="">Pregunta
                    <a class="btn btn-primary agregar add" href="javascript: void(0)" type="button"><span></span>Agregar</a>
                </p>
        </div>
        <div class="duplicate all">
            <div class="up-box-question" style="text-align: center">
                <a class="remove-aditional" href="javascript: void(0)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-question" style="text-align: center">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="type-question-text">Tipo de Pregunta</label>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <select class="form-control select" name="">
                                            <option value="1">Text</option>
                                            <option value="2">Verificar</option>
                                           </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row ocultar">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="type-question-text" for="">Titulo</label>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="" class="form-control text general" placeholder="Número de indentificación">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row verificar">
                        <div class="text option" style="margin-top:10px; text-align: center">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary addRow" href="javascript: void(0)" type="button"><span></span>Agregar Opcion</a>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="optionRow">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Si resuelto, Gracias!